# Divide the list into 2 equal Parts

Tags: algorithm, list, sorting

I have a list which contains random numbers such that Number >= 0. Now i have to divide the list into 2 equal parts (assume list contains even number of elements) such that all the numbers contain in first list are less than the numbers present in second list. This can be easily done by any sorting mechanism in O(nlogn). But i don't need data to be sorted in any two equal length list. Only condition is that (all elements in first list <= all elements in second list.) 
So is there a way or hack we can reduce the complexity since we don't require sorted data here?

Comment: What you've described is the base of quick sort, I guess the question originates there. You find a median and based on that you do what you're asking. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: See http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/to-find-the-median-of-an-unsorted-array

Comment: Thanks Robert, i got an idea how to resolve it

Answer (score 4):

If the problem is actually solvable (data is right) you can find the median using the [selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm). When you have that you just create 2 equally sized arrays and iterate over the original list element by element putting each element into either of the new lists depending whether it's bigger or smaller than the median. Should run in linear time.

@Edit: as gen-y-s pointed out if you write the selection algorithm yourself or use a proper library it might already divide the input list so no need for the second pass.

Comment: correct, except that the selection algorithm already separates the array into two parts, one smaller than the median and one larger.

Comment: @gen-y-s very well spotted, some methods just return the `median` though so it depends if you're writing it yourself or using a third party.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk .. Can you list some methods which return median directly?

Comment: @Neer1009 I think Apache Commons Math has a Median class that uses the selection algorithm for this. You can also have a look at SSJ (stochastic simulation in Java)